# Is Recovery Mode necessary to flash to newer Android version manually?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, rom-flashing, recovery-mode, sony-xperia

My phone (Sony Xperia Go) seems to be not able to boot into Recovery Mode

Is there some alternative way or tool to use for flashing ROM? (to latest kitkat mod). To avoid recovery mode

I have fastboot working on computer

Comment: Are you rooted? What happens when you try to boot to recovery? Do you have a custom recovery installed?

Comment: @RossC Yes phone is rooted and unlocked. It seems like the phone is just rebooting. Same when I try from QuickBoot or adb. Don't know if I have a custom recovery installed? I have made a backup with Nandroid and flashed that with fastboot. no change

Comment: Did you install a custom recovery? You'll need one to boot into... very strange though.

Comment: How do I install a custom recovery? See also http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/81832/xperia-go-boot-into-recovery-mode

Comment: Saw that already, I'll answer how to install a recovery below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: Installing the custom recovery using the tools below requires a rooted Xperia Go. Generally root isn't always necessary and a device can be rooted by flashing a pre-rooted ROM for example, and a recovery flashed via [fastboot](/questions/tagged/fastboot) as another example. Also note it can brick your device. I take **no responsibility for the below if your device turns into a shiny paper weight**

The below is for a Windows Machine only:

To install a custom recovery, [clockworkmod-recovery](/questions/tagged/clockworkmod-recovery) in this case:

1. Place the archive you just downloaded to your Desktop.
2. Extract files from the archive to your Desktop.
3. Turn ON the USB debugging function on your device by going to `Menu>>Settings>>Developer options>>USB debugging`.
4. Connect the device to your PC using the USB cable.
5. Double-click on the install.bat file and the utility should launch.
6. Follow the instructions displayed on your screen.
7. Once Recovery’s installed, reboot the device.
8. You’re all set!

Comment: What does this do? Where is the custom recovery? And how to do it on a mac? Can't seem to get windows to work. Sry I'm a noob at all this ;)

Comment: It installs a custom recovery, it's in the link I gave... and it needs windows.

Comment: @mowgli also I'd add this; READ, READ and READ more. You can never know enough about this sort of thing, if you mess up you could end up with a non working device. If you can't understand things above, look them up, read the XDA thread lots of times. The more research now the less panic later when your phone goes dead!

Comment: Yeah I've been reading and reading ;) I actually messed up the phone by just flashing a kitkatrom with fastboot. No boot. Then I used the Emma tool to install factory default (and it's working again). So that's where I am now

Comment: I don't see a custom recovery in your link, only questions. Edit: nevermind, I'll find one ;)

Comment: Ok now I installed a custom recovery. SuperSU says I need SuperSU PRO to give access to ADB shell and QuickBoot.. damn this is so confusing and advanced

Comment: @mowgli Great! :) Glad to hear it. Let me just give the other reminder everyone is sick of hearing from me: BACKUPS! Make backups, copy them onto your PC for good measure! It means you can install ROMs knowing you have a full system image (or [tag:nandroid]) backup of your device you can restore from recovery whenever you want! Have fun!

Comment: Backups? yeah right :D jk

Comment: It looks like I have upgraded to KitKat successfully :) Do I just backup with NanDroid now, and that will make a complete copy of my phone? Or how do you suggest backing up?

Comment: I would have backed up **before** installing KitKat, but do it now anyway. It creates a .zip file of the ENTIRE system image. If you restore it your system will be **exactly** as it is now. That means OS, apps, app data, launcher, EVERYTHING. :) Do it through recovery. Trust me, the feeling when the phone bootloops and you have no ROM or backup on the device is pretty awful, I've done it a few times before I learned my lesson!

Comment: Oh, I already backed it up before installing it. My question was more: is NanDroid ok for that or do you suggest other way?

Comment: Oh, nandroid is the way I always use for sure. To backup my apps for differnt ROMs I use Titanium Backup (Free on play store) Nandroid is your emergency backup if things go wrong, titanium is there for when you install a new ROM and want to restore your apps and their data.

Comment: @RossC You wrote in your answer that you need to root, and that's incorrect. I have an HTC, I unlocked my bootloader using HTC dev, used fastboot to flash recovery (fastboot flash recovery recovery.img), and installed ROM in recovery with ROM.zip on my sd card. I never rooted my original ROM. Although this his isn't an HTC, but an sony, the process shouldn't be much different.

Comment: @user3949142 to use the method I provided you need root. You don't necessarily need it at all in general, and you can flash pre rooted ROMs etc, but in this instance for that program to work it needs to be rooted according to the developer, I'm just giving his advice. I've added a note to my answer to say that, and to clarify root isn't a necessity in all cases.